# .NET client getting "not well formed" XML response from Axis web service

Tags: xml, soap, .net-2.0, axis

I have a simple .NET app that makes a SOAP call to a third party Axis web service. When I trace the HTTP traffic, I see that the Request looks fine, however I'm getting an exception: "Response is not well-formed XML." The return object is null, as it seems the XML can't be deserialized.

One question regarding the various namespace declarations inside the wsdl. Several of these declarations point to URLs / domains that no longer exist. Could this cause any problems?

From the wsdl document:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://domaindoesntexist.com/"  
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"  
xmlns:impl="http://domaindoesntexist.com/"  
xmlns:intf="http://domaindoesntexist.com/"  
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

A sample HTTP response with incriminating data removed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 05 Jun 2009 13:54:59 GMT

7cb
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<someMethod xmlns="http://test.com/services/myservice/">
</someMethod>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: We did resolve this, but unfortunately I don't recall the source of the problem, as it's been almost a year and a half.

Answer (score 1):

**It has been my experience that namespace URLs do not have to be actual existing URIs.** Consistency is what is desired, so internal XML schemas can be built for validation. The intent was (I believe) to host the namespace definition at that location so that developers could go there and check it out, but then people got lazy.

I may, in fact, be quite wrong on that latter count.

Answer (score 0):

> Several of these declarations point to
>   URLs / domains that no longer exist.
>   Could this cause any problems?

Sure. Have you tried updating the webservice in your project?

Comment: The webservice is maintained by a third party, so I can't update it. They claim that they use the wsdl as-is to generate working Axis clients.

From the WSDL doc:

<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://domaindoesntexist.com/"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
xmlns:impl="http://domaindoesntexist.com/"
xmlns:intf="http://domaindoesntexist.com"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: Is the webservice public so I could debug it? What kind of project is this? Did you create the webservice reference through Visual Studio or are you trying to cobble this together from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after looking into Wireshark trace it was found that there is a Proxy server which is inserting some headers in the XML payload

webservice is trying to load xml

*"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2rZ3fnB2rMzDjipXgQz8ObOcEczeOIO74sa17YK5hrPkt62qce12BItOmuvPrC/WD8N3xZzBeBceBbiAA0IlsR2aXxd479Es7wO9va2cGpF/cc284gI.K5FXbOR5PUPx00EqNRjCdbdU4fv/JXN2alGDzGVlgCnRK5/6DJlAkcED2011-06-08T15:35:21.505Z"*

which obviously will not load.

**The complete tcp stream in my case**

POST /ls/ws/auth HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.3615)

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

SOAPAction: ""

Host: ??????

Content-Length: 487

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive

2PUldqLs2KqUkJryFiZPQJI.D6RCixeMu443SLd7dCF2qrzws0E2JYatTqm8wD2CuFrSVHEjvJHIXfiLy6w9yBagentfp093.0.1.9019HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2011 15:35:21 GMT

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

X-Cache: MISS from dgtproxy1.skybroadband.com.ph

Connection: close

.1

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Connection: close

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

2rZ3fnB2rMzDjipXgQz8ObOcEczeOIO74sa17YK5hrPkt62qce12BItOmuvPrC/WD8N3xZzBeBceBbiAA0IlsR2aXxd479Es7wO9va2cGpF/cc284gI.K5FXbOR5PUPx00EqNRjCdbdU4fv/JXN2alGDzGVlgCnRK5/6DJlAkcED2011-06-08T15:35:21.505Z